# Would the LinkedIn API allow you to analyse follower growth of a company page and personal profile over time?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have a company page and personal profile on LinkedIn, and I would like to analyse and see how each of these have developed in terms of followers and more (engagement rate, posts, etc.) over time. For example, I would like to see how I have grown in followers from month to month in the last year. And it would also be interesting to figure out the relationship between timing (e.g. by weekday) and engagement rate of my posts.

As a beginner in working with API, I am curious to know if the LinkedIn API would allow me to do this. And if so, is this use of their API open to everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "yes", you can get that info.
Short answer:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A2414183&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1551398400000,end:1552003200000),timeGranularityType:DAY)
```

If you want the details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/follower-statistics

You might consider some authorization issues like:

- Use the Organizations and Brand APIs to create, modify, and delete information on your organization and brand, view analytics and notifications, and share content. You can also enable members to follow organizations and view suggested organizations using this API.

see this: [Organizacion Access Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-access-control)

Company Pages and Showcase Pages are surfaced as Organization and Brand resources respectively. [...] These entities may only be modified by members who have been granted specific organizational roles.

Hope this helps!
Regards.

Comment: Thank you! Would you happen to know to answer to my other short question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803714/linkedin-api-error-of-redirect-uri-from-httr

Comment: I'll take a look at that question!