# LinkedIn API error of redirect uri from httr

Tags: r, api, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, httr

I'm trying to access LinkedIn's API using R and the `httr` package.

When I execute the last `oauth2.0_token()` function, in order to gain an authorization token, I get the following error from LinkedIn: `"The redirect_uri does not match the registered value"`.

I've set my redirected url on the LinkedIn Developer site to `http://my_app_54321`

Does anyone know what the solution is?

```
# Packages
library(httr)

# Client info
clientid <- "my_id"
secret <- "my_secret"

# App
app <- oauth_app(appname = "app name", key = clientid, secret = secret)

# Endpoints
endpoint <- oauth_endpoint(base_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2", 
                           authorize = "authorization", access = "accessToken")

# Access token
token <- oauth2.0_token(endpoint = endpoint, app = app)
token
```

[image: LinkedIn error message]

Comment: I think that this could help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570194/linkedin-invalid-redirect-uri-this-value-must-match-a-url-registered-with-the

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fryla-CristianMarucci!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `my redirected url` to the following solved it since I just needed the application to run locally.

```
http://localhost:1410/
```

The comments from the GitHub of `httr` package pointed in this direction:

https://github.com/r-lib/httr/blob/master/demo/oauth2-linkedin.r

Comment: I added this in the Linkedin dev portal, and now I get "Authentication complete. Please close this page and return to R." in the browser window. However after in R I get `Authentication complete.
Error in oauth2.0_access_token(endpoint, app, code = code, user_params = user_params,  : 
  Bad Request (HTTP 400). Failed to get an access token.` I wonder if it still works for you?

Comment: Hi, could you post your code, create a new question and tag me? Then I can take a look :)

Comment: Thank you, I posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621616/r-httr-linkedin-api-bad-request-http-400