# R httr Linkedin API: Bad Request (HTTP 400)

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, httr

My question is closely related to this one: [LinkedIn API error of redirect uri from httr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803714/linkedin-api-error-of-redirect-uri-from-httr/63143758?noredirect=1#comment112395339_63143758)

Here is my code:

```
library(httr)

clientid <- "MY-ID"
secret <- "MY-SECRET"

app <- oauth_app(appname = "app name", key = clientid, secret = secret)

endpoint <- oauth_endpoint(base_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2", 
                           authorize = "authorization", access = "accessToken")


token <- oauth2.0_token(endpoint = endpoint, app = app)
```

As I do this, the browser opens with the message `Authentication complete. Please close this page and return to R.`

In R I get this:

```
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
Error in oauth2.0_access_token(endpoint, app, code = code, user_params = user_params,  : 
  Bad Request (HTTP 400). Failed to get an access token.
```

I use the client id and secret given to my app on https://www.linkedin.com/developers/ and I did set the redirect URL there to `http://localhost:1410/`.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, R version 3.6.3, httr version ‘1.4.2’.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing the `scope` argument in `oauth2.0_token()`.

Examples of LinkedIn scopes you could use would be: `scope = "r_organization_social"` or `scope = "rw_organization_admin"`.

So it could look like:

```
token <- oauth2.0_token(endpoint = endpoint, app = app, scope = "rw_organization_admin")
```

It depends on how much access you've got and what data you'd like to request through the API

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem changing :token <- oauth2.0_token(endpoint = endpoint, app = app, scope = "w_member_social")