# R httr MS Dataverse API: Bad Request (HTTP 400), Define scope

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, powerapps, httr, dataverse

My question is closely related to this one: [R httr Linkedin API: Bad Request (HTTP 400)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621616/r-httr-linkedin-api-bad-request-http-400).

I have an application set up in Azure AD that I would like to use to get data out of MS Dataverse using R. I am new to APIs, so I first set it up in Postman. I was successful at getting to my data in Postman, but it did not require a Scope parameter.

I attempted to recreate what I did in Postman in R...

```
require(rvest)

dataverse_api = oauth_endpoint(request = NULL, 
   authorize = "REDACTED",
   access = "REDACTED",
   base_url = "REDACTED")

API.Key = "REDACTED"
API.Secret = "REDACTED"

App = oauth_app("EPS Project Development", key = API.Key, secret = API.Secret)

API.token = oauth2.0_token(dataverse_api, App)
```

This caused my browser to open and give me an error saying a scope was required. I have been searching through documentation to find nomenclature for scopes, but haven't been successful. I have found several documents ([1](https://help.alteryx.com/20213/designer/microsoft-dataverse), [2](https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/11/Extensibility_and_Integration/Integration_Builder/Use_Integration_Builder/Register_an_OutSystems_Integration_Builder_app_in_your_system/How_to_register_SharePoint_Online%2C_Microsoft_Dataverse%2C_or_Microsoft_Dynamics_365_apps_in_the_Azure_Active_Directory), etc.) that are somewhat peripheral that list options such as "ReadWrite.All" or "Files.ReadWrite.All", but my understanding is that these are permissions which are different from Scope. Because I don't know what I'm doing, I tried several of them as such:

```
require(rvest)

dataverse_api = oauth_endpoint(request = NULL, 
   authorize = "REDACTED",
   access = "REDACTED",
   base_url = "REDACTED")

API.Key = "REDACTED"
API.Secret = "REDACTED"

App = oauth_app("EPS Project Development", key = API.Key, secret = API.Secret)

API.token = oauth2.0_token(dataverse_api, App, scope = "User_impersonation")
```

The result is always the same. The browser opens with a message `Authentication complete. Please close this page and return to R.`, but in R I get:

```
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
Error in oauth2.0_access_token(endpoint, app, code = code, user_params = user_params,  : 
  Bad Request (HTTP 400). Failed to get an access token.
```

From the link I cited above as being a similar question, I understand that I am still missing the Scope parameter. But I do not know where to get the Scope parameter for MS Dataverse. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You should try to ask for the openid scope as well, does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am unfamiliar with that term. What is an openid scope? And who do I ask for that?

Comment: scopes are what you are trying to get access to, if you want to authenticate with AzureAD I think you need to add the openid scope as wel, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there are other options, but in case it's helpful to anyone else I was able to make it work by specifying the scope as the Dynamics 365 URL followed by .default. For me this looks like: `https://org593dc393.crm4.dynamics.com/.default`